# C++ char array: error while copying data

Tags: c++, syntax, char, lvalue

I have an array:

```
CHAR m_manuf[256];
```

I am trying to copy a value to this array as:

```
m_manuf = "abacus";  //This shows error
```

I also tried this variation:

```
char abc[256] ="abacus";
m_manuf = abc; //Shows error as left value must be l-value
```

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array, but you can *copy* to it. But if you're programming in C++, why don't you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: You can also do something like `char * m_manuf = "abacus";` probably.

Comment: @CollinD It's generally a bad idea to have a non-const pointer to a string literal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant' copy an array like that, instead of you can do,

```
CHAR    m_manuf[256];
strcpy(m_manuf,"abacus" );
```

Or

```
char * m_manuf = "abacus";
```

Or

```
char abc[256] ="abacus";
strcpy(m_manuf,abc );
```

***Note : The better way to handle char arrays are using std::string,***

Answer (score 0):

A constant char array is good enough for you so you go with,

```
string tmp = "abacus";
char *new = tmp.c_str();
```

Or you need to modify new char array and constant is not ok, then just go with this

```
char *new = &tmp[0];
```